# Updating dom with select tag change listner

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Got the following code:

```
<form action="./index.html" method="get">
                <select class=" locationdropdown selectdropdown pull-right" id="prayerMethod">
                  <option value="ISNA">ISNA</option>
                  <option value="MWL">MWL</option>
                  <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                  <option value="Makkah">Makkah</option>
                  <option value="Karachi">Karachi</option>
                  <option value="Tehran">Tehran</option>
                  <option value="Jafari">Jafari</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" style="display:none;">
                </form>


<script>
var mySelect = document.getElementById("prayerMethod"); 
    $(mySelect).change(function(){
         // $(this).parent('form').submit();
        // alert(mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value );
        prayTimes.setMethod(mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value );
    });
    </script>
```

I would like it to update the dom with the new value given by the select tag which is inputted into the prayTimes() method. How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to update in the DOM?

Comment: And what's the function you're using? And *why* are you passing the result of `document.getElementById()` into the jQuery selector, instead of simply `$('#prayerMethod')`?

Comment: @DavidThomas you're right. I was just quick and dirty trying things

Comment: @bagonyi `var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [43, -80], -5);` requires a method of calculations, hence why the .setMethod(). But I want to update the method live to change the calculations and the output of times